# CSS Shadows for IE Browsers?

Tags: shadows

Can anyone show me or direct me in the right direction for placing CSS shadows for IE Browsers.  Here is my current code:

```
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666;          
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666;
```

I need to make the IE look the same as the other browsers.

Many thanks & Happy holidays.

Erik

Answer (score 0):

Generally you have an "IE Fix" separate CSS file that would take care of the shadows with a background image.